# [IzPack][Mac] "This directory can not be written!"

Tags: macos, hidden, izpack

I'm trying to make an installer with IzPack 4.3.5. 
Unfortunately the installer throws up this message:

> This directory can not be written! Please choose another directory!

I'm trying to install something in "~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin".

Here's my install.xml:

```
<info>
    <appname>WorldEdit - Client User Interface installer</appname>
    <appversion>1.0</appversion>
</info>

<guiprefs width="640" height="480" resizable="yes"/>

<locale>
    <langpack iso3="eng"/>
</locale>

<resources>
    <res id="InfoPanel.info" src="info.txt"/>
    <res id="TargetPanel.dir" src="path.txt"/>
</resources>

<panels>
    <panel classname="InfoPanel"/>
    <panel classname="DefaultTargetPanel"/>
    <panel classname="TargetPanel"/>
    <panel classname="InstallPanel"/>
    <panel classname="FinishPanel"/>
</panels>

<packs>
    <pack name="WorldEdit - Client User Interface" required="yes">
        <description>Minecraft 1.4.7 met Forge en WorldEdit - Client User Interface</description>
        <file src="../Inhoud/minecraft.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH"/>
    </pack>
</packs>
```

And my path.txt:

```
${ENV[USER_HOME]}/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
${USER_HOME}/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin
```

or alternatively

```
${ENV[HOME]}/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin
${ENV[USERPROFILE]}/Library/Application Support/minecraft/bin
```

for *ix and windows systems respectively.

I would suggest using the former solution.